# Passing Function from Server to Client

Tags: javascript, node.js

for a recent project of mine I need to pass two functions from my server (written in node.js) to a client javascript tag. Actually to be completly correct, the client side javascript calls an XML request and I want to return some data and two functions for him which he should be able to use.

Second thing is I want to store a javascript function into a database in the server and then fetch it if the client requests it.

Anyone knows how this can be archieved and has some experience with it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your use case ? What did you try so far ? Any code you can share ?

Comment: So far I only have done research about if this is possible at all. If it isn't, there is no sense in actually start programming this, because it would be a key feature. The use case can be pretty easily described as this: client connects and sends XML request to server that he is connected. Server returns him and json (jsonp?) with a dataset and a function. The dataset gets run in the function and the return val is returned to the server, where the client gets new data and a new function.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to do this with an AJAX request ? How about serving the JS code directly in a <script> tag in page ? You can use a templating engine like EJS if you need to modify the code for each client.

Comment: It would be nice if it was with an ajax request. Since I then dont have to wait until the user refreshes a page or loads another page with my script tag to give him new data and a new function.

Answer (score 2):

Note: you should really consider doing this in an HTTPS connection.

OK, so you want to receive code from the server and run it on the client. You could inject a script tag to the body and let the browser execute it. However, since you trust the code. I would simply use an `eval` call since that's what you'll doing anyway.

Here's how it would look in an Express app:

```
// server
function hello() {
  alert('hello');
}

app.get('/get/js/code', function (req, res) {
  res.send({
    code: hello.toString(),
    start: 'hello()'
  });
});

// client (with jQuery)
$(function () {
  $.getJSON('/get/js/code', function (json) {
    eval(json.code + ';' + json.start + ';');
  });
});
```

Comment: So there really is no other way than executing it via eval()? How would I actually pass parameters now to the start function?

Comment: You could add a <script> tag to the DOM, but the browser would parse it and essentially eval it. My example has a JSON response so you can pass parameters alongside the code.